# How many declaration of variables can be done in a C program?

Tags: c, limit, variable-declaration

In a C program,we usually declare less number of variables. Whether is it possible to declare 'n' number of variables?
for ex: int a,int b,int c .......
Or whether compiler gives me an error?

Is there a maximum limit for the declarations of variables?

Comment: What do you mean by “less number”? Are you just asking if there's a maximum, or something else?

Comment: If you think there's a problem, then you need to learn about arrays.

Comment: Is there a maximum limmit

Answer (score 4):

A compiler is not obliged to have an upper limit.  But if it has a limit, it can only be so small.

C does define *minimal* maximum limits.

See C11 5.2.4.1 Translation limits

Examples:

4095 external identifiers in one translation unit
511 identifiers with block scope declared in one block
127 parameters in one function definition
1023 members in a single structure or union

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit limit for number of variables. Moreover this is connected to specific compiler, but there are indications about what minimal number of scopes, local variables and identifiers length must be supported to call it standard conformant.

The limit itself is not anyhow connected to memory available at runtime.

Any limit (constraint) on the source code must be explicitly given in compiler documentation (this is statement taken from the C standard indication, paragraph limits).

Comment: The ability to *declare* variables (i.e. what the compiler accepts) and the ability to actually *allocate* them in memory can both be limits. GCC, for example, supports computers with several GB or more where actually the maximum size of a symbol table (don't know if there is any) might be a limit, down to AVR Tiny which has as much as 512 **bytes** where definitely too many variables will prevent a program from running.

Comment: Ok, I think this is covered in "documentation in compiler" as from specification, or am I missing something? Ability to allocate them in runtime is not compilers problem, but if compiler cannot allocate them, yes it is.